Hollow core slab - Opening
A hollow core slab is used in my project which dimension is 3.2m X 1.1 M X 0.15m having strength of 50 MPa. But our team is decided to make opening for plumbing line and electrical conduit going from ground floor to 1st floor and sizes of opening is 50 mm and the total no. Of opening is 8 so I want to know how much strength of slab decreases and is it safe to proceed

You need to provide information on the location of the penetrations, their layout pattern, and the slab's geometric characteristics. However, here is a paper to read and try to find the answers yourself. https://www.pci.org/PCI_Docs/Publications/PCI%20Journal/2018/July-August/17-002_Prakash_JA18.pdf
